# What counts as Dwarvish stonework?

Tags: dnd-5e, dwarf, artifacts

From [Spell save DC on a wish spell cast from a magic item](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102614/spell-save-dc-on-a-wish-spell-cast-from-a-magic-item), I realized that if I try to sleight of hand then teleport I can get away with an artifact. If this first sleight of hand fails though I plan to use time stop instead to steal the Axe and fly away once I attune.

However, **what counts as “dwarvish stonework” to use the axe's teleport?**

I am a dwarf, so can I just carve a dwarven insignia into a stone and call it “dwarvish stonework”, or do I need more?

Comment: The answer almost certainly requires studying the description of the artifact you're asking about. What artifact is this question about?

Comment: @Marq Please don't answer (or [partially answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534)) in comments. That's not what the commenting privileges are for.