# Does Rod of the Pact Keeper boost Spell Save DC of Ring of Shooting Stars?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock, spellcasting

The *Rod of the Pact Keeper*(+1) increases my Warlock's spell save DC by 1.  With an 18 Charisma at level 8 my spell save DC is 16. (8+3+4+1)

I just received a Ring of Shooting Stars.    The *ball lightning* feature, and the *shooting stars* feature, require a DC 15 Dexterity save to avoid lightning or fire damage respectively.  For both features, the same text is used.

> That creature must make a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw.

Since my Warlock is attuned to the Rod of the Pact Keeper(+1), do they now have to make a DC 16 Dexterity saving throw to avoid the lightning or fire effects, or, is the DC 15 fixed and non-modifiable?

(A related question on the RoSS's effects [like *faerie fire*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159741/22566) is not the same as this one).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The DC is 15 because the Ball Lightning and Shooting Stars features are not warlock spells.

[Rod of the Pact Keeper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-the-pact-keeper) says (emphasis mine):

> While holding this rod, you gain a bonus to spell attack rolls and to the saving throw DCs of *your warlock spells*.

These features of the [Ring of Shooting Stars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-shooting-stars) are not warlock spells, so the Rod of the Pact Keeper does not affect the DC of these features. The DC is 15, as stated in the item description.

Comment: I know you say they aren't *warlock* spells, but wouldn't it be simpler to just say that they aren't even *spells*?

Comment: @Medix2: Notably, the Faerie Fire option of the *ring of shooting stars* lets you expend a charge to cast *faerie fire* - which is a spell - from the ring, but the *rod of the pact keeper* doesn't affect that spell's DC either because it's not a warlock spell.

Comment: @V2Blast *Unless* you are an Archfey Warlock. Regardless, the OP mentions precisely that spell (and a question about it) and how it is a different situation

Comment: @Medix2 That might be a nice exception, but I just found an item that will specify 'using casters spell save DC' which is the Harp of Ollamh. *The spells use your spellcasting ability and spell save DC*  Since the ring lacks that specificity, the spell save DC would seem to me to default to whatever the item DC is.

Comment: arrgh, accepted it but forgot to upvote!  Corrected.  